# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "testapp23://" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, ios9

I get this error on real device:

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "testapp23://app" - error: "(null)"

This is the code I use:

```
let openAnotherAppURL = NSURL(string: "testapp23://app")!     
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(openAnotherAppURL)) {
//some code
}
```

I added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to my info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
     <string>testapp23</string>
</array>
```

And it seems to "recognise" the second apps scheme scheme, cause when I use something else like "testaapp23" I get a different error message (which makes sense):

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "testaapp23://app" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme testaapp23"

I have the second app installed on the device

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>testapp23</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try in target application in its Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>testapp23</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I've created demo project with 2 target: source and target apps. Everything working OK, when I run target, than source and checking `canOpenURL:`.

Comment: Yes, i have the same in my info.plist for second app

Comment: OK, let me test it.

Comment: @MadhuAvinash have you run your target app at least once? I've created demo project with 2 targets and only `NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"testapp23://"]; BOOL can = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL];` - it's OK.